# Should I keep track of incrementing AccountNumber in separate table?

Tags: database, sqlite, database-design

A set users each may have an AccountNumber, so in order to create a new account, I will increment the highest existing account number by 1. How would you keep track of the last issued number?  Of course one could loop through all accounts to check, but is there any reason why one would perhaps chose to keep a separate table of either the last issued number, or all numbers?

I'm just looking at a few thousand accounts, so it's not that i'm worried about optimization.

Comment: What does this have to do with C# or .net? Looks like it doesn't have anything to do with it, so please remove the `c#` and `.net` tags.

Comment: The best approach is to build an Account table that will store your AccountID that will be assigned to all your users.  The AccountID should be an identity that will auto increment.  Anytime you add a new user, you'll look-up the AccountID in the Account table and assign it to the user.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should probably use [`IDENTITY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx) if you're using MS SQL, or equivalent if you're using some other DB.

That will keep track of the ids properly, even when two people are trying to create an account at the same time.

Comment: Thx! I'm using SQLite and FluentNhibernate, but not stored procedures (as I haven't learned it yet). So does this mean I should make the account number the table's Identity column, as now I have a separate column "Id"? And how would I make it start at a certain number?

Comment: @bretdog, see [the documentation for Autoincrement in SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html).

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Oracle use a sequence. http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/sequences.php 
For MSSQL use something like this. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlcat/archive/2006/04/10/sql-server-sequence-number.aspx

Answer (score 1):

*The question was originally tagged .Net and C# so I assumed MSSQL, which it isn't. I don't know how much of this answer is valid when used with Sqlite.*

There are several strategies to handle this. I think that these two are most interesting:

1. Use an `IDENTITY` column, which will automatically take care of race conditions when two processes create accounts at the same time, rolled back transactions and other things. The downside with an `IDENTITY` columns is that you may get holes in your number series. If this is not acceptable, you need to use the another approach.
2. Handle the numbers yourself. I would prefer a special table, containing the next free number. When you create a new account you have to do this inside a transaction, using an isolation level that locks the free-number table immediately when you read it and keeps the lock until the updated number is stored. This is awkward to do and will give less scalability, but you can guarantee that you get continous numbers.

Either way, you should have a unique key on the account number column as an extra safety.

Comment: What about just using AutoId Key, and have that as the AccountNumber, then you don't have to worry about generating the next Unique key??

Comment: Maybe 2nd option is more reliable. Considering that database type may change, and I will have control over the first-issued account number, which I want to specify.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid I'm not familiar with SQLlite. But most SQL engines these days have some sort of "autonumber" feature.

Failing that, create a sequence. The DB engine should manage the sequence for you so you never get duplicate numbers.

If for some reason neither of those things is possible, then you can create a separate table to hold the last-used id. Be sure to read it using "select for update" to avoid race conditions.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using SQL Server you can use use the Max function, which will return the highest value of the row you look at.

Update:
Simple Example.
`Select Max(AccountNumber) from Accounts`

Update: 
Ok, Maybe I was wrong don't use Max, as that would cause some problems. :( Sorry.

Comment: And pray for no race conditions

Comment: This will not work properly if two processes try it at the same time. They can both get the same id.

Comment: Would using IDENTITY not be the same though?